# User has write permissions but cannot write to files

Tags: permissions, mount, samba

I am using a python script to write (and sometimes overwrite) data files. I can write new files just fine, but am getting `permission denied` when trying to write to existing files. What's strange is that I believe I have write permission for these files. Here's what it looks like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername etc etc etc
```

Can anyone offer any explanation as to why I might not be able to write to these files? It should be noted they are stored within a mounted network drive.

EDIT:
As requested, here is the code that opens the file (dataset is just a set of numbers in a string that's used to identify the run that was done):

```
outdir = /Volumes/file/path/
file = outdir + dataset + ".dat"
f = open(file,"w")
```

and the error I'm receiving is:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Volumes/file/path/dataset.dat'
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's opening the files for (re-)writing?

Comment: Better than that, write an error message that leaves no questions, like `cannot write to '%s' (%s)`, where the first %s is replaced by the pathname and the second %s  is the string corresponding to the errno.

Comment: Can you write to those files if you do it in some other manner, e.g. by using `echo "foo" >> /path/to/network/file`?

Comment: How is the file system mounted? Perhaps it is mounted read only... See `/proc/self/mounts`

Comment: Edits reflect the information that was asked for. Basile, I'm still relatively new to command line stuff, could you elaborate on how I could investigate that?

Comment: It's telling me /proc/self/mounts: No such file or directory

Comment: Does `f = open(file,"r")` give an error, too?

Comment: This is on Mac OS X and the filesystem is an SMB mount, just like your [other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214897/new-files-in-a-mounted-directory-are-being-created-with-a-different-user-and-rem), right?

Comment: This is on Mac OS X, I believe. I'm not having any trouble reading the files. I am even able to open them in Finder, where I can see that the file is locked, and it tells me that I do not have permission to unlock the file.

Comment: Christopher - when I try that I am seeing `//drive_to_be_mounted/path on /Volumes/path (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by myusername)`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Although, I have since figured out how to mount correctly (I believe) - required me to mount to my specific user account's file system, not just the file system in general.

Comment: Is it possible that the nosuid could be my issue? From what I can gather, that means that it doesn't allow set-user-identifier bits to take effect. I can't really understand completely what that means, but it seems like it could be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Nosuid is irrelevant

Comment: Any chance you might know what is relevant?

Comment: Keep `nosuid`: This is a security thing. If you allow `suid` on a network/removable drive then you may allow someone to gain root access. Some for `nodev`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't (yet?) have an answer. You wondered if `nosuid` was part of the issue. My admittedly terse reply was that it isn't, so it can safely remain in place.

Comment: Your example shows `/Volumes/file/path/dataset.dat`. Did this file exist _before_ you attempted to write to it? If so, please confirm output of `ls -l dataset.dat`. If not, what are the permissions for the parent directory, `/Volumes/file/path`?

Comment: @roaima Yes, the file exists before I attempt to write it. The output of `ls -l dataset.dat` is as shown above: `-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername etc etc etc`